# Why isn't the speed of a mass in a vertical loop in a gravitational field constant?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, centripetal-force

So I know that if we look at for example a yoyo in a vertical loop, from the energy perspective, at the bottom of the loop, the yoyo will have the most kinetic energy. And since the mass of the yoyo doesn't change, that means the speed has become greater.

But what I don't get is that if we look at it from the centripetal force equation, since the yoyo is maintaining a constant radius and the mass is not changing, it's going to have the same centripetal force all the way around. And if the centripetal force is the same, and mass and radius is the same, from the equation Fc = (mv^2)/r , the speed must stay the same throughout the motion. But from the energy perspective, this does not happen. So I don't know how to solve this contradiction.

Summary: Why doesn't the speed of a mass in vertical circular motion on earth stay the same? There seems to me to be a contradiction between looking at the energy equations and looking at the centripetal force equations.

Answer (score 1):

the centripetal forces at your yoyo is changing , but this has nothing to do with energy , the centripetal force does not change the velocity, it just adjust to the greater velocity, at the bottom the centripetal force is greater, an ant traveling on your yoyo would experience it.

Comment: But that can't make sense because when we usually solve problems like this (usually to find what tension is) at the bottom of the yoyo, we usually make the (tension - the force of gravity) equal to the centripetal force the yoyo would have experienced at the top of the loop. So shouldn't centripetal force be the same throughout? @trula

Comment: I can understand the force of tension being greater at the bottom, but I'm pretty sure the centripetal force is the same. Right?

Comment: Wait I think the problem relies on me thinking that the centripetal force stays the same throughout. I think it should, but now I'm thinking it doesn't have to.

Comment: two situations: you have a mass on a string, and move it on circle, then the tension on the string is caused by the centripetal force.you habe a yoyo climbing up an down a string, the centripetal force does not make the tension of your string.